# data binding inside (click) is not working in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind the url which is stored in the config file is not getting bindable inside the (click) event of angular 4 but the interpolation is working inside the src tag of img. See the below example i have tried.

**app.config.ts**

```
export class AppConfig {
    //Local API URL for Testing
    public readonly apiUrl = "http://localhost:4200/";
};
```

For this i have imported the app.config.ts in component.ts file. When i did this for image tag, then string interpolation is working fine. See below for reference.

```
<img src="{{this.apiUrl}}/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="Home" />
```

The issue with the below code when i am trying to use interpolation in click event.

```
 <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="type == 'admin'">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('{{this.apiUrl}}/dashboard','_self')">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
```

Getting the below error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 18 in [navigateExternal('{{this.apiUrl}}/dashboard','_self')] in ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@35:46 ("li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="type == 'admin'">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" [ERROR ->](click)="navigateExternal('{{this.apiUrl}}/dashboard','_self')">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
   "): ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@35:46
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using click you can directly assign as,

```
<a target="_self" href="{{apiUrl}}/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```